# Node.js install Synology ds212+ error

Tags: node.js, installation, environment

I'm currently installing the Node.js environment on my Synology ds212+ and I have a problem when I'm running a line command.

When I'm trying to do

> ./configure --prefix=/opt/node --without-snapshot

The terminal give me this error:

> Node.js configure error: No acceptable C compiler found!
>
> ```
>     Please make sure you have a C compiler installed on your system and/or
>     consider adjusting the CC environment variable if you installed
>     it in a non-standard prefix.
> ```

The problem is that I have gcc installed and when I'm using the gcc -v, the terminal return me the current version of my compiler.

Does anyone has this error when installing on a synology environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out by myself. The things to do is to execute this line :

```
git checkout v0.4.11
cp /opt/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 /usr/lib
cp /opt/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 /usr/lib
```

Now you can do the make and the make install.

Have fun.

Comment: hi, i also need theese two files for my ds212+. But not for Node.js. i need them for ZendDebugger. unfortunately the C compiler in not installed on my system. I have no knowlede, if its possible to copy the files directly to the path /usr/lib. Is it possible to download the files directly, maybe on your ds?

Comment: Look into installing ipkg and using it to install gcc and make. http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Overview_on_modifying_the_Synology_Server,_bootstrap,_ipkg_etc

Answer (score 6):

I just met this problem, simply `ln -s /opt/bin/gcc /opt/bin/cc` will make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that gcc is usually installed to an odd place on the synology (/opt/bin/gcc). Giving configure the right name for it seems to work.

```
CC=/opt/bin/gcc ./configure --prefix=/opt/node --without-snapshot
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to install a gcc compiler on your MAC. Follow the instructions here:

http://www.mkyong.com/mac/how-to-install-gcc-compiler-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: And your comment would even be useful, if Simon was using a Mac. But as he specified in his post, he's on a Synology DiskStation, and those are running a modified version of Linux (heavily modified, mind).